# How to inject a Jakarta enums in a Spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have a class which constructor takes a [Jakarta enums](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/enums/Enum.html). I'm trying to find how I can easily inject it via an [Spring](http://www.springframework.org/) XML aplicationContext.

For example :

The enum :

```
public class MyEnum extends org.apache.commons.lang.enums.Enum {
    public static final MyEnum MY_FIRST_VALUE = new MyEnum("MyFirstValue");
    public static final MyEnum MY_SECOND_VALUE = new MyEnum("MySecondValue");

    public static MyEnum getEnum(String name) {
        return (MyEnum) getEnum(MyEnum.class, name);
    }
    [...other standard enum methods]
}
```

The class in which to inject :

```
public class MyService {
    private final MyEnum status;
    public MyService(MyEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The application context :

```
<bean id="myService" class="MyService">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="MyFirstValue" />
</bean>
```

Of course, with this I have a `no matching editors or conversion strategy found` error. Is there an easy integration between Spring and the Jakarta enums ? Or should I write my own PropertyEditor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `<util:constant>` tag in Spring.  It will require you to add the schema to your xml definition. So you would wind up with the following:

```
<bean id="myService" class="MyService">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <util:constant static-field="MyEnum.MY_FIRST_VALUE"/>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The definition and usage of the tag (including the XSD def) is found [here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but it is very verbose (far too much to my taste) :

```
<bean id="myService" class="MyService">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="MyEnum" factory-method="getEnum">
            <constructor-arg value="MyFirstValue" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted-up Spencer's answer but found that this will work as well.  In this example, you just need to specify the **index, type**, and **name** in the constructor-arg.

```
<bean id="myService" class="MyService">
<constructor-arg index="0" type="com.package.MyEnum" value="MyFirstValue" />
</bean>
```

I based this off of an  error message I received:

> *(hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)*